# Cannot able to pass the form values to a php page when its inside div modal

Tags: php

Here is my code. Its not working properly. The values inside the form is not posting to the php file, ie login.php.

```
<div id="myModal1" class="modalDialog">
<div>
<h1>
<a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
</h1>
<div class="login-form">
<div class="head">
<img src="img/mem2.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<form method="post" id="myform" method="post" action="login.php">
<li><input type="text" name="uname" required class="text" placeholder="USERNAME" /><span class=" icon user"></a></li>
<li><input type="password" name="pwd" required placeholder="PASSWORD" /><span class=" icon lock"></a></li>
<div class="p-container">
<input type="submit" name="login" value="SIGN IN" />
</div>
<a href="register.php"><h5>Register Here</h5></a>
</form>
<div>
</div>
</div>  

<?php
if(isset($_POST['uname']))
{
  echo "success";
}
else
echo"failure";
?>'
```

I always get failure as an output which means that the values are not posting from the form. Please anyone help me to resolve this soon.

Comment: You are trying to access email field which is not in your form. change it to `$_POST['uname']`

Comment: You also appear to have edited your question and messed up the formatting :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['uname'])) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "failure";
}
```

There's no `email` input in your form. So I'm using `uname` here which is in your form. Make sure that these match up in any form.

Also, watch how you use the braces in the PHP code. You use them for the first part of the if statement and then don't for the else operator. Try to be consistent or you'll be asking for trouble.

TIP: If you are not getting the expected post results, you can always output the complete POST. Put `var_dump($_POST);` in your code and you'll see exactly what you are receiving from the form.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I changed my php codebut still am getting the same error.

Comment: Did you try `var_dump` before the if statement to see what you are actually getting?

Comment: Yes, its returning " array(0) { } ". Is there any mistake with my html code?

Comment: Try this: `<form method="post" id="myform" action="">`

Comment: Yes. Its working. Thanks allot. But why is that? Cant i write a php page separately and post the values there?

Comment: You can, but it looks like your PHP code was inside the same page? You edited your original question so I can't be sure

Comment: You need to put the PHP code int he target file - not in the source.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have an input called "email", therefore the isset() function is (correctly) returning false

Try using your uname field instead, like so.

```
if(isset($_POST['uname']))
....
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Even after i changed it, am getting the same output.

Comment: Hmm, strange - you do have method="post" twice in your <form> tag, possibly remove that? And make sure you enter a new value in the field, don't just leave the placeholder in there (some browsers remove the placeholder before submitting)